# React web app works fine for me but for client only works on anonymous tab

Tags: caching, apache2, create-react-app

For whatever reason, my react app only works on an anonymous tab(chrome,firefox,safari) for my client (on previous versions it worked normally), but it works fine for me, it works on any pc/phone and browser that i tried it (except internet explorer). Another issue, is with internet explorer/edge,it fetches a more than year old version of the web app.

I assumed that it was a cache problem, so I tried to clean my client cache and to force the website to fetch the new version (through apache configs, html meta and by using unregister() from registerServiceWorker )

On apache I added:

```
    Header Set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header Set Expires "Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
    Header Set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
    Header Unset ETag
    FileETag None
```

On my react index.html

```
 <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
 <meta http-equiv="expires" content="timestamp">
 <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

The website doesn't show any error when it fails to run normally (on a non anonymous tab).